# Error CS1729, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes, Fields, and FieldValues:Fields as follows:

```
enum FieldType
{
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    String
}

class Fields
{
    public FieldType type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string GetFieldDeclaration()
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case FieldType.Boolean:
                return name + " tinyint(1)";
            case FieldType.Integer:
                return name + " int";
            case FieldType.String:
                return name + " varchar(2048)";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

and FieldValues:Fields

```
class FieldValues:Fields
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> dictionary { get; set; }

    FieldValues(FieldType newType, string newName)
    {
        type = newType;
        name = newName;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }
```

These classes represent some values that will be extracted from a xls and inserted into a database. In the main program,

```
List<Fields> tableFields = new List<Fields>()
        {
            new Fields() { name = "id", type = FieldType.Integer },
            new Fields() { name = "ECE", type = FieldType.Boolean },
            new Fields() { name = "TC", type = FieldType.Boolean },
            new Fields() { name = "Categories", type = FieldType.String },
        };



        string createQuery = "CREATE TABLE `poi_specs_mgu_ece_1.6` (";

        //creaza tabelul in functie de cate field-uri(coloane) sunt in lista
        for(var i = 0; i < tableFields.Count; i++)
        {
            createQuery += "\n\t" + tableFields[i].GetFieldDeclaration() + (i == tableFields.Count - 1 ? string.Empty : ",");
        }
        createQuery += "\n);";

        //[WORK]create insert statement

        List<FieldValues> fieldValues = new List<FieldValues>()
        {
            new FieldValues(tableFields[0]) {
                dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                {
                    {0, "test" },
                    {1, "test" },
                    {2, "test" },
                    {3, "test" },
                    {4, "test" },
                    {5, "test" }
                }

            },
            new FieldValues(tableFields[1]) {
                dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                {
                    {0, "x" },
                    {1, "x" },
                    {2, " " },
                    {3, "x" },
                    {4, " " },
                    {5, "x" }
                }

            },
            new FieldValues(tableFields[2]) {
                dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                {
                    {0, "x" },
                    {1, "x" },
                    {2, "x" },
                    {3, "x" },
                    {4, " " },
                    {5, "x" }
                }

            },
            new FieldValues(tableFields[3])  {
                dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                {
                    {0, "Car" },
                    {1, "Travel" },
                    {2, "Stopping Possibilities" },
                    {3, "Petrol Stations" },
                    {4, "Rest Areas" },
                    {5, "Travel" }
                }

            },
        };

        string createQuery2 = createQuery + "\n INSERT INTO `poi_specs_mgu_ece_1.6` (";

        for (var i = 0; i < tableFields.Count; i++)
        {
            createQuery2 += "\n\t" + tableFields[i].GetFieldDeclaration() + (i == tableFields.Count - 1 ? string.Empty : ",");
        }
        createQuery2 += ")\n VALUES ( ";



        for (var i = 0; i < fieldValues.Count; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < fieldValues[i].dictionary.Count; j++)
            {
                createQuery2 += "\n\t" + fieldValues[i].dictionary[j];
            }
        }
        createQuery2 += " \n);";
        File.WriteAllText("output.txt", createQuery2);
        Console.WriteLine(createQuery2);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

When compiling I get the following error:

> Error CS1729 'FieldValues' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.

I don't really understand why exactly my constructor from FieldValues doesn't work here.

Comment: Because your constructor takes _two_ arguments `newType` and `newName`, but you only provide one. Just like the error message states.

Comment: " I don't realy understand why exactly my constructor from FieldValues doesn't work here" - It does not "work" because it is not called :)

Comment: Another question is whether you need to make the constructor (or one constructor overload) more accessible. It is currently private. Use keyword `internal`, for example, to make it accessible from the entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you that you have a constructor declared as:

```
FieldValues(FieldType newType, string newName)
```

and you try to call it with only 1 parameter:

```
new FieldValues(tableFields[2])
```

You can overload a constructor with one that accepts 1 parameter or you need to give the second parameter when you call it.

**EDIT:**

One Solution might also be to overload the constructor with one where you can  pass a variable of type `Fields` as parameter.

```
class FieldValues:Fields
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> dictionary { get; set; }

    public FieldValues(FieldType newType, string newName)
    {
        type = newType;
        name = newName;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }

    public FieldValues(Fields values)
    {
        type = values.type;
        name = values.name;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }
```

Then you can still assign the dictionary on your own.

```
List<FieldValues> fieldValues = new List<FieldValues>()
{
    new FieldValues(tableFields[0]) {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "test" },
            {1, "test" },
            {2, "test" },
            {3, "test" },
            {4, "test" },
            {5, "test" }
        }

    },
```

**EDIT2:**

As I just recognized. The overload would have not worked because in your post your constructor is not `public`! This is essential to be able to call it from any other class. I corrected this mistake in my answer.

Comment: yes, but tableFields[o] represents a name plus a type.
`List<Fields> tableFields = new List<Fields>()
            {
                new Fields() { name = "id", type = FieldType.Integer },
                new Fields() { name = "ECE", type = FieldType.Boolean },
                new Fields() { name = "TC", type = FieldType.Boolean },
                new Fields() { name = "Categories", type = FieldType.String },
            };`

Comment: @RăzvanBălan I made an edit showing an example of an overload of a constructor that might solve your problem and make the code work without big changes. Check it out

Comment: overloading the constructor like you said didn't work. can you tell me how exactly should assign the dictionary?

Comment: @RăzvanBălan The overload does not work because your constructor is not `public`. I copy pasted your code into my answer and forgot to correct this mistake. My fault. I corrected it now. This time it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Your class `FieldValues` has the following (non-public btw.) constructor:

```
FieldValues(FieldType newType, string newName)
```

However you call it like this:

```
new FieldValues(tableFields[0])
```

Hence the error. You probably meant to pass the type too, e.g:

```
new FieldValues(FieldType.String, tableFields[0])
```

Or add another constructor that implies a specific type, e.g:

```
public FieldValues(string newName)
{
    type = FieldType.String;
    name = newName;
    dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
}
```

Or (as @JeppeStigNielsen pointed out)

```
public FieldValues(string newName) : this(FieldType.String, newName)
```

Or you move the type parameter and make it optional

```
public FieldValues(string newName, FieldType newType = FieldType.String)
```

---

On a side note, `"penis"` is not a good placeholder text during development, you might forget to take it out (pun not intended). I've taken the liberty of replacing it with `"test"` in your question.

Comment: The extra constructor could just _chain_ the old one, as in `internal FieldValues(string newName) : this(FieldType.String, newName) { }`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Depending on what he's actually trying to do, that might be the smartest way to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the "penis" thing, I just copy pasted it without checking it.

Comment: I thought that constructiong FieldValues ctor with a type and name, as well as tableFields list, where, for example, tableFields[0] has also a name and a type

Comment: @RăzvanBălan No, the compiler can not make that assumption. You need to call the constructor (or any method for that matter) with the exact signature. You can find more detailed information on overload resolution [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your Ctor of FieldValues takes two parameters, `FieldType newType` and s`tring newName`. You're calling it with only one Parameter: `new FieldValues(tableFields[0])`.

What you want is probably:

```
new FieldValues(tableFields[0].Type, tableFields[0].Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your support. I've overloaded the constructor like this

```
public FieldValues(string newName)
{
    type = FieldType.String;
    name = newName;
    dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
}
```

and the dictionary part like this

```
new FieldValues(tableFields[0].ToString()) {
                    dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                    {
                        {0, "test" },
                        {1, "test" },
                        {2, "test" },
                        {3, "test" },
                        {4, "test" },
                        {5, "test" }
                    }
```

I know this was noob stuff but it helped me since I am a fresh starter in c#.
Live and Learn, though.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you have found a solution and learned something. You could at least accept (and or upvote) one of the answers that helped you. By this you would return the favour to the people who helped you.